# Manipulate a word document ("caller"/"context") from an excel workbook ("callee"/"controller") that was opened by it

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

## Background

I have a Word-macro in `Normal.dotm` that opens an Excel-workbook `Reference Check.xlsm`.

The macro uses `RegExp` as well as `Range.Find` to find strings of a certain pattern, and then it places this information onto sheets in the Excel-workbook.

This is the basic template:

```
Sub GetReferencesAndHyperlinksToExcel()
' Shortcut Key: Ctrl+[Num *]

    Dim oRegex As New RegExp
    Dim oRegExMatches As MatchCollection
    Dim oRegExMatch As Match
    Const strPattern As String = "(my pattern)"

    Dim SourceDocument As Document
    Dim oStory As Range
    Dim hl As Hyperlink

    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim R as Excel.Range

    ' Set the context
    Set SourceDocument = ActiveDocument

    ' Load the spreadsheet
    Set xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\...\Reference Check.xlsm")

    ' Set starting range to write to
    With xlWorkbook.Worksheets("Reference Checks")
        .Range("ref").ClearContents
        Set R = .Range("ref")(1, 1)
    End With

    ' Initialise regex
    With oRegex
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = strPattern
    End With

    ' ==== Iterate through story ranges, then execute regex and write matches and hyperlinks to the spreadsheet ====

    ' ==== Iterate through story ranges, then iterate through hyperlinks and write hyperlinks to the spreadsheet ====

End Sub
```

The Excel-workbook does some calculations and lookups (with pre-filled column formulas) against a Data Table within the Workbook.

Using that information, I manipulate the active Word document (the "caller" or the "context") in **predictable**^ ways.

^If it's predictable, then we should be able to use a macro to do the work for us.

## The problem

I want to use the now-open Excel workbook `Reference Checks.xlsm` as a "console" or "controller", where I can change some data, and use data, to perform operations on (make changes to) the document.

To do this, I believe I need to somehow be able to refer to the original "caller" or "context", i.e. the Word document that was Active when I originally called it (`Set SourceDocument = ActiveDocument`), from within the now-open Workbook. This means that either:

1. Macros within Excel (tied to Buttons) `Reference Check.xlsx` act on `SourceDocument` *(preferred)*, or
2. Macros within Excel (tied to Buttons) `Reference Check.xlsx` call a Macro within Word `Normal.dotm` and then act on the `SourceDocument`* *(if this is possible, the above should be)*, or
3. Various macros within `Normal.dotm` act on `SourceDocument`* *(workable, but clunky)*

*Note: This must actually be `SourceDocument` (the "caller" or "context") and not `ActiveDocument`, because it is possible that as I switch between windows, another document could become `ActiveDocument`.

## Things I've thought of

For option 1, use a global variable in `Reference Checks.xlsm`, then when I load the workbook, set the reference to `SourceDocument`. This is my preferred option. I have no idea how to do this, however.

For option 3, use a global variable in `Normal.dotm`, set the reference to the workbook when I open it, then read information in the workbook when I call the macros. A drawback would be that I have many macros I might call, and I would have to have many public subs (makes `Normal.dotm` quite unwieldy).

## Help

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested this and it worked perfectly with Office 2010.

**Note** that you need the Excel Library in your Word Normal Template and the Word Library in the `Excel Reference Check.xlsm`

You will need the following:

Sub in the `ThisWorkBook` module in the  `Reference Check.xlsm`.

So in your Excel VBA Project -> Microsoft Excel Objects -> ThisWorkBook

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExcelWordController(WordDocFromWord As Document)

    'If you are wanting to use it as a Document then _
        you will need the Word Library in Excel

    MsgBox WordDocFromWord

    'Just put some funny text inthe doc for a test
    WordDocFromWord.Range(0, 0).Text = "Yeah Baby It works"

    'Here you can then call someother Sub or so some processing

End Sub
```

Then in your `Word` `Normal` project:

```
Option Explicit

'Sub in Word Normal
Sub ExcelControlWordFromWordInitiation()

    'Obvisouly you alrady have the Excel Library in the Word Doc

    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    'xlWorkbook is a object in the Word Excel Library
    'So I changed the name
    Dim RefCheckWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim R As Excel.Range

    Dim SourceDocument As Document
    Set SourceDocument = ActiveDocument

    'You want to be able to see the Excel Application
    xlApp.Visible = True

    Set RefCheckWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\Reference Check.xlsm")

    'Calling the Sub in Excel from Word
    Excel.Application.Run "ThisWorkBook.ExcelWordController", SourceDocument

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I needed.

Comment: Minimal solution: **Controller.xlsm > ThisWorkbook:** `Public SourceDocument As Word.Document \ Sub SetContext(ByRef wdDoc As Word.Document) \ Set SourceDocument = wdDoc \ End Sub` **Normal.dotm > Module1:** `Sub LoadController() \ Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application \ Dim xlWb As Excel.Workbook \ Dim SourceDocument As Document \ Set SourceDocument = ActiveDocument \ xlApp.Visible = True \ Set xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName:="C:\...\Controller.xlsm", ReadOnly:=True) \ xlApp.Run "ThisWorkbook.SetContext", SourceDocument \ End Sub`